# Refactor non-blocking nodejs do..while loop

Tags: mysql, node.js, loops, nonblocking

I'm writing an api in node.js. The first webservice endpoint - `/create` - creates a new db entry with a randomised 6-character hash, much like a bit.ly hash.

Having done something similar in PHP, I've written a `do..while` loop which generates a random string and checks my mysql db (using node-mysql) to make sure it's free. I've also got a counter in there, so I can fail after `x` iterations if need be.

```
var i = 0;
var alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'];
var hash = null;
var success = false;

do {

    // generate a random hash by shuffling the alphabet, 
    // joining it and getting 6 chars
    hash = alphabet.sort(function(){ 
        return 0.5 - Math.random();
    }).join('').substr(0,6);

    console.log(i + ': checking hash ' + hash);

    // see if it exists in the db
    db.query("SELECT hash FROM trips WHERE hash = " + hash, function(err, results){

        if(results.length == 0) {
            // the hash is free to use :)
            success = true;
        } else {
            // the hash is already taken :(
            success = false;
        }

    });

    // increment the counter
    i++;

} while(success === false && i < 10);
```

I currently only have one hash in my db (`abcdef`), but the loop is getting to ten and failing because it thinks each new hash is already present.

I'm pretty sure this is because of the non-blocking nature of node.js. This is obviously A Good Thing, but in my case I need the loop to block until the query has returned.

I'm pretty sure I could hack this by doing something like:

```
var q = db.query(...);
```

But I know that's throwing away a major feature of node.js.

Is there a code pattern for this sort of need?

Comment: Note that I've made a small change to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm pretty sure this is because of the non-blocking nature of node.js.

Yes.

> This is obviously A Good Thing, but in my case I need the loop to block until the query has returned.

No, you most certainly don't want to do that.

Embrace the asynchronous approcach. Work with call-backs:

```js
function generateHash(onSuccess, onError, retryCount) {
    // generate a random hash by shuffling the alphabet, 
    // joining it and getting 6 chars
    var hash = alphabet.sort(function(){ 
        return 0.5 - Math.random();
    }).join('').substr(0,6);

    // see if it exists in the db
    db.query(
    "SELECT hash FROM trips WHERE hash = '" + hash + "'", 
    function(err, results){
        if (results.length == 0) {
            // the hash is free to use :)
            onSuccess(hash);
        } else {
            // the hash is already taken :(
            if (retryCount > 1) {
                generateHash(onSuccess, onError, retryCount - 1);
            } else {
                onError();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

generateHash(
  function(hash) { console.log('Success! New hash created: ' + hash); },
  function() { console.log('Error! retry limit reached'); },
  6
);
```

Comment: you already in callback handler, there is no recursion, call is routed via event loop

Comment: @Andrey If I call `generateHash()` from within `generateHash()`, that would be recursion in my book. The event loop does not matter here, the outermost function call will not return until all recursive calls are resolved.

Comment: A big thank you to you both, this is exactly what I was looking for. I'm enjoying the learning experience!

Comment: @Tomalak - I think you have an extra right parenthesis towards the end of `setTimeout`, just before the microseconds.

Comment: @Tomalak - you don't call generateHash from geneateHash. You call it from anonymous function - just look at stack frame in debugger or print Error.stack before setTimeout

Comment: @Andrey Woops. Of course, you are right. My mistake. I've removed the `setTimeout()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
var i=0;

function generateHash(callback) {
    // generate a random hash by shuffling the alphabet, 
    // joining it and getting 6 chars
    hash = alphabet.sort(function(){ 
        return 0.5 - Math.random();
    }).join('').substr(0,6);

    console.log(i + ': checking hash ' + hash);

    // see if it exists in the db
    db.query("SELECT hash FROM trips WHERE hash = " + hash, function(err, results){

        if(results.length == 0) {
            // the hash is free to use :)
            callback(null, hash);
        } else {
            // increment the counter
            i++;
            if (i < 10)
                generateHash(callback); //another attempt
            else
                callback('error'); // return result

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: +1 from me (I think transporting the retry count in a parameter is cleaner than creating an outer-scope variable for it, though)

Comment: agree, param vs outer scope variable is better